# running file from exchange powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I would like to know how to run a file like this:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity arrwest -SearchQuery “Subject:MLIS Volume Report”,”From:cmctrymullin”,”Sent:today” -DeleteContent
Search-Mailbox -Identity ceringle -SearchQuery “Subject:MLIS Volume Report”,”From:cmcmtrullin”,”Sent:today” -DeleteContent
```

etc

I have about 1000 lines that I need to run in the exchange 2010 powershell

How do I do this?

Comment: i found that all you do is put it in a ps1 file. but when i do run it, i have to confirm EVERY SINGLE line and press Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue this command in the shell before executing your script:

```
$ConfirmPreference = "None"
```

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/15/confirmpreference.aspx)